# Not able to autowire a bean in task scheduler class in Java

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I've written a task scheduler in Spring. Its running properly. Now my condition is I'm trying to inject one bean into the listener. But, it returns me null object. But if the same bean is injected into a controller/component, it works fine. Please let me know if I need to make any modifications.

Here is my code

My configurations in application context configuration file

```
<task:scheduler id="testScheduler" pool-size="1" />
<bean id="testListener"
    class="com.dev.util.TestListener" >     
</bean>
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="testScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="testListener" method="run"
        fixed-delay="60000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

The bean which I'm trying to inject

```
<bean id="getEmployeeServiceAdapter" class="com.dev.adapter.GetEmployeeServiceAdapter">     
</bean>
```

And finally my class

```
public class TestListener {

    @Autowired
    static
    GetEmployeeServiceAdapter getEmployeeServiceAdapter;

    public void run() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Hii");
        // Code 
    }

}
```

when I do in debug mode, and place my cursor on the object, it gets as null

Comment: Hello, I think you can't autowire static objects.Try remove static.

Comment: @OresteViron, tried with that also, still it doesn't work

Comment: You need to remove static and either add autowire attribute like <bean id="getEmployeeServiceAdapter" class="com.dev.adapter.GetEmployeeServiceAdapter" autowire="byName">     
</bean>  or add <property name="getEmployeeServiceAdapter" ref="getEmployeeServiceAdapter" /> as child for bean testListener.